# jquery scrollTo catch before load

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have this script for my navigation:

```
$(function () {
    $("a").click(function (e) {
        var target = $(this).attr("href");

        if (target.match("^#")) { // Check to see if we are an anchor link
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default only if we are :)

            navigate(target);
        }
    });
});

function navigate(target) {
    var offset = $("header").outerHeight(true);
    var $target = $(target);

    if ($target.length > 0) {
        var position = $target.offset().top - offset;

        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: position
        }, 500);
    }
};
```

the main thing to notice about this is the **offset** because the navigation is **fixed**.
My html for this looks like this:

```
<nav id="navigation" class="navbar navbar-main" role="navigation">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Strategies", "Index", "Strategies")</li>
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#packages">Packages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#work">How we work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#clients">Clients</a></li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Blog", "Index", "Blog")</li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

note the **hrefs** here. They are using hashes which is as you would expect. But as you can see there are 2 pages that take you to another separate page (Strategies and Blog).
On these pages the menu looks like this:

```
<nav id="navigation" class="navbar navbar-main" role="navigation">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="@Html.ActivePage("Home", "Index")">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
            <li class="@Html.ActivePage("Strategies", "Index")">@Html.ActionLink("Strategies", "Index", "Strategies")</li>
            <li><a href="/#services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="/#packages">Packages</a></li>
            <li><a href="/#work">How we work</a></li>
            <li><a href="/#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="/#clients">Clients</a></li>
            <li class="@Html.ActivePage("Blog", "Index")">@Html.ActionLink("Blog", "Index", "Blog")</li>
            <li><a href="/#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

the only difference is that all the links now have **/#** instead of just **#** which will first navigate them to the home page, then it moves it to the position.

Because this is a normal link, it is not handled by my navigate string, so I created this function:

```
function getHashtag() {
    var href = location.href; // get the url
    var split = href.split("#"); // split the string; usually there'll be only one # in an url so there'll be only two parts after the splitting

    if (split[1] != null) {
        navigate(split[1]);
    }
}
```

which gets the hash and then calls my **navigate** function explicitly.

My whole script now looks like this:

```
$(function () {
    getHashtag();

    $("a").click(function (e) {
        var target = $(this).attr("href");

        if (target.match("^#")) { // Check to see if we are an anchor link
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default only if we are :)

            navigate(target);
        }
    });
});

function getHashtag() {
    var href = location.href; // get the url
    var split = href.split("#"); // split the string; usually there'll be only one # in an url so there'll be only two parts after the splitting

    if (split[1] != null) {
        navigate(split[1]);
    }
}

function navigate(target) {
    var offset = $("header").outerHeight(true);
    var $target = $(target);

    if ($target.length > 0) {
        var position = $target.offset().top - offset;

        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: position
        }, 500);
    }
};
```

As you can see, I am calling **getHashtag** after the page load, what I need to do is call it before anything is loaded and override the default action (probably e.preventDefault).
Does someone know how I can do this?

Cheers

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for Is it possible that you want to prevent the default "jumpto" behavior in case of an url with a hash?

Comment: You can put your "getHashtag" call in an inline script in before of all in the <head> part of your page in order to get it executed before the full page is loaded. But your "navigate" function use some of jQuery methods, that expects the jQuery library is loaded. You can try without using jQuery, with JavaScript's getElementById and others functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be going about this the wrong way...

You're talking about preventing default behavior. So you're assuming there's an event to respond to. There is a hashchange event you could listen to, but I don't know if it'll trigger when there's navigation to a different page.

About triggering the script before anything is loaded: put the script in your `<head>`-tag, and trigger your code there. However, since nothing is loaded yet, you also can't jump to the correct position yet, as the document will still be empty.

I suggest you take a different approach: by default, use css to hide your page. When all the JavaScript that you want to run before showing anything is done, change the css to show the page. That way you have full control over when you want to display anything.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Hans I have modified my code to this:

```
$(function () {
    resetPosition();

    $("a").click(function (e) {
        var target = $(this).attr("href");

        if (target.match("^#")) { // Check to see if we are an anchor link
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default only if we are :)

            navigate(target);
        }
    });
});

function resetPosition() {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 500, function () {
        var href = location.href; // get the url
        var split = href.split("#"); // split the string; usually there'll be only one # in an url so there'll be only two parts after the splitting

        $(".body").removeClass("ajax");

        if (split[1] != null) {
            navigate("#" + split[1]);
        }
    });
};

function navigate(target) {
    var offset = $("header").outerHeight(true);
    var $target = $(target);

    if ($target.length > 0) {
        var position = $target.offset().top - offset;

        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: position
        }, 500);
    }
};
```

I have a wrapper around my body with the class **.body** and every page starts with a section, so I could create my css like this:

```
.ajax { 
    background-image: url(Images/ajax-loader.gif); background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center; height: 500px;
}

.ajax section { 
    display: none; 
}
```

and I added the **.ajax** class to my **.body** class which automatically hides everything.
When the page loads, it will move to the top of the page and then when it has got there, it will remove the **.ajax** class from **.body** revealing our content and then it will scroll to our **hash** only if we have one.

Perfect :)